# Replacing empty with length in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I can no longer use :empty in this snippet and i need to replace it so the text is added and wrapped if there is exactly 1 tr found , no more , no less. I think this is done with .length , but what i tried didn't work.

```
$("#MyTable tr:empty").text("Insert Text Here").wrapInner( "<tr class='oddtablerow'><td class='noevent'></td></tr>" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.length` like this:

```
var $rows = $("#MyTable tr");
if ($rows.length == 1) {
    $rows.text("Insert Text Here").wrapInner( "<tr class='oddtablerow'><td class='noevent'></td></tr>" );
}
```